# Fill missing objects in an array of objects based on the property of an object in a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, set

The code below adds an object element with revenue = 0 for one of three categories (Class, Workshop, Training) if they missing for that month (so need to evaluate the combination of the **category** and **month** properties of each element)

```
const rawdata = [
  { category: 'Class', month: '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 100 },
  { category: 'Workshop', month: '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 140 },
  { category: 'Training', month: '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 300 },
  { category: 'Class', month: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 200 },
  { category: 'Workshop', month: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 200 },
  { category: 'Class', month: '2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 134 },
  { category: 'Workshop', month: '2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 124 },
  ...
];
const categories = Array.from(new Set(rawdata.map(x => x.category)));
const months = Array.from(new Set(rawdata.map(x => x.month)));
for(const month of months) {
  for(const category of categories) {
    const found = rawdata.find(element => element.month == month && element.category == category);
    if(!found) rawdata.push({ month, category, revenue: 0 });
  }
}
```

That changes the array above to (note the elements with revenue: 0):

```
[
  { category: 'Class', month: '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 100 },
  { category: 'Workshop', month: '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 140 },
  { category: 'Training', month: '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 300 },
  { category: 'Class', month: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 200 },
  { category: 'Workshop', month: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 200 },
  // Next object element was added
  { category: 'Training', month: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 0 }
  { category: 'Class', month: '2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 134 },
  { category: 'Workshop', month: '2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 124 },
  // Next object element was added
  { category: 'Training', month: '2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', revenue: 0 }
  ...
];
```

Is there a more elegant approach? What I'm doing works but doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: Will you please add what are the inputs,outputs and desired solution clearly

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
myArray.forEach(element=>{
    if(!element.revenue){
        element.revenue = 0
   }
 }
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: This code sample checks to see if there's an revenue property on the array elements, setting it to zero if not.